# support as many screen possible on android

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have published an Android app, and i would that it support as many screen as possible. I have develop my app for support as many screen as possible (i have different graphical resources and xml files for each type of screen density).
In my xml files i've declared:

```
 <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

but when i go to the play store, my app is not compatible with my device (a nexus 5, xxhdpi screen) and some devices of my friends (some one plus one). How can i do to make it compatible with as many device as possible

Comment: what api are you targeting?

Comment: This may not be a screen size issue necessarily. What API levels have you indicated support for in your AndroidManifest.xml? Also, does your app require special hardware? see here for how permissions can affect who sees your app http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Comment: My target api is 21 and i've no particular hardware requirements. Now i've upload again my app, and is still in prod (waiting to be approved) and inside list of compatible devices, appear nexus 5 and oneplusone